# VB.NET 2012, how to make ErrorProvider's message stay visible?

Tags: vb.net, errorprovider

Does anyone know how to make the ErrorProvider's message stay visible when the mouse is over the ErrorProvider's icon?  The message goes away or becomes not visible after a few seconds.  People are complaining that there isn't enough time to read the message and they have to move the mouse away then back onto to the icon to see the message again.

Edit:
Tried Steve's suggestion (below) but the message still goes away

```
    ErrorProvider1.BlinkRate = ErrorBlinkStyle.NeverBlink
    ErrorProvider1.BlinkStyle = ErrorBlinkStyle.NeverBlink
    ErrorProvider1.SetError(Me.TextBox1, "Error")
```

This link [Set ErrorProvider ToolTip Duration](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-us/224e24ae-c5e9-456a-8324-e4ce5fa92f60/set-errorprovider-tooltip-duration) asks the exact same question I'm trying to ask here, unfortunately the question in the link is unanswered too.

Comment: It's a Windows Form Application

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-us/3013f20a-f9af-4ea9-9226-7b2019ee1631/tooltip-of-errorprovider-class-gets-lost

Comment: I haven't really understood your question. The link above seems to contain a possible solution if it works with current NET versions.

Comment: I was roused by your answer but the tooltip / message would not stay visible longer than a few seconds, I edited my original question to show a sample of code that I tried.  The link above... I see where it states (you can't change any of the timings of it's tooltip).  Can you post this as the Answer to this question so I can choose it as the most useful answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB 2012, Framework 3.5, Windows Forms Application.  For reasons unknown to me, if one sets the `BlinkRate` to something between 10 and approx 4500 and sets the `BlinkStyle = ErrorBlinkStyle.AlwaysBlink` the ErrorProvider's tooltip / message will stay visible indefinitely as long as the mouse is hovered over the ErrorProvider's icon.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ErrorProvider.BlinkRate = 250
    ErrorProvider.BlinkStyle = ErrorBlinkStyle.AlwaysBlink
End Sub
```

Comment: Winforms, VB, .NetFramework 4.5
- the tooltip vanishes after 2 seconds
- with every blink of the ErrorProvider symbol (I guess) the "hover event" is fired in the background, therefore the message gets "refreshed" | 

as you said, setting the blinkrate smaller than the two seconds will work, though I don't like the blinking...